# Selective analysis in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau (9.2.4), how can I selectively analyze for a value?

I have one measure `Teleop Defense A` that has a value of either `Portcullis` or `Cheval de Frise`. I have another measure `Teleop Defense A Makes` that is an integer. How can I get the average value of `Teleop Defense A Makes` only when `Teleop Defense A` equals `Portcullis`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AVG(IF [Teleop Defense A] = "Portcullis" THEN [Teleop Defense A Makes] END)`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do it .

1. Create a filter on `Teleop Defense A` and select `Portcullis` for your analysis .

OR

2. Create a calculated field as `custom_calc_field`

   ```
   AVG(CASE WHEN `Teleop Defense A` = `Portcullis` THEN `Teleop Defense A Makes` END)
   ```

Use the above field as your measure instead of `Teleop Defense A Makes`.

Let us know if this worked .

Comment: `CASE WHEN` did not work for me. I edited your suggestion and this worked for me: `AVG(IF [Teleop Defense A] = "Portcullis" THEN [Teleop Defense A Makes] END)` Thank you